# Taking correct input in array of strings

Tags: java, args

My code isn't taking the first string as input. Instead it starts directly with the second one. Can anyone tell me, what am I doin' wrong?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
class StrSort
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int size;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter the size of the array : ");
        size=s.nextInt();
        String[] array=new String[size];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter string "+(i+1)+" : ");
            array[i]=s.nextLine();
        }
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.print("\nStrings are sorted.");
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\nString "+(i+1)+" : "+array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use proper indentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

Comment: Please put a language tag on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the newline after the size is not consumed.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
class StrSort
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int size;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter the size of the array : ");
        size=s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();  // Consume newline left-over
        String[] array=new String[size];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter string "+(i+1)+" : ");
            array[i]=s.nextLine();
        }
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.print("\nStrings are sorted.");
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\nString "+(i+1)+" : "+array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll need a bit more explanation please.

Comment: `Scanner#nextInt` does not read the last newline character of your input. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/1521064